# openid connect with swagger-ui

Tags: swagger, openid-connect, swagger-ui, openapi

I'm trying to get the openIdConnect working with openapi3 and swagger. I use the following tool and config:

https://editor.swagger.io/

```
openapi: 3.0.1
info:
  description: "This is a sample."
  version: "1.0.0"
  title: "Swagger Petstore"
paths:
  /pet:
    get:
      tags:
      - "pet"
      summary: "Add a new pet to the store"
      description: ""
      operationId: "addPet"
      responses:
        "405":
          description: "Invalid input"
      security:
      - petstore_auth:
        - "email"
components:
  securitySchemes:
    petstore_auth:
      type: openIdConnect
      openIdConnectUrl: https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration
```

When I click authorize and select the last option in the authorization options, I get:

```
Authorization Error
Error 400: invalid_request
Required parameter is missing: response_type
```

How do I set the `response_type` in openapi3 spec?

Comment: Yeah. Unfortunately it does not mention anything about setting the response_type

Comment: Swagger does not send the response_type parameter to the oauth service and it is a required according to googles document   https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/openid-connect